# conn.sendall(os.system(... .sh)) not send for my client python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want send for my cliente in socket server :

```
conn.sendall(os.system('./sensor1.sh'))
```

The code for sensor1.sh is:

```
#!/bin/bash
i2cget -y 1 0x48 0x00 w |
awk '{printf("%.1f\n",(a=(\
(("0x"substr($1,5,2)substr($1,3,1))*0.0625))\
)> 128?a-256:a)}'
```

this work fine, i can see the variance of my temperature sensor, but i cant send information for my cliente. the error is:
must be string or buffer, not int

how i resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

`os.system` return exit status of subprocess. If you want send the output of `sensor1.sh`:

```
import subprocess

...
conn = ...
...

out = subprocess.check_output(['./sensor1.sh'])
conn.sendall(out)
```

Comment: @DuarteValente, please show error message/traceback. BTW, I didn't use any Python-3.x feature.

Comment: `out = subprocess.check_output(['./sensor1.sh'])`

Comment: why do you think `shell=True` is necessary?

Comment: this is the erros :                                              out = subprocess.check_output(['sensor1.sh'], shell=True)
File "/ur/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 544, in check_output
raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '[sensor1.sh']' returned non-zero exit status 127

Comment: i dont have erros, but i dont recieve anything

Comment: @DuarteValente, If you want output of `./sensors1.sh` printed, Put `print(out)` before `conn.sendall(out)` line.

Comment: i want send the valor of my sensor, and recieved in my program Visual Basic, i canot recieved anything why?

Comment: @DuarteValente, Please post another question about your Python/Visual Basic socket related problem. (with `python`, `vb`, `socket` tag).